# Enable remote computer server to appear as local IP address on my LAN

Tags: linux, networking, router, apache-http-server

I would like a remote Apache server to be accessible on my LAN network as a local server on the 10.1.0.* series.

Essentially so that on my LAN, when you type in e.g. 10.1.0.5, you have access to the Apache server interface as set up in /var/www of the remote computer. The remote Apache server should connect to the public IP of my LAN automatically on the boot of the remote computer.

I already have a public IP through which the remote Apache server can connect to my LAN and port forwarding (both UDP and TCP). So on the LAN end everything was already correctly configured by a predecessor.

What do I need to do on the remote computer to make this happen?

Comment: I am confused.  `10.1.0.5` nor `192.168.1.30` exist outside of your network. So neither can be considered remote and are both considered to be local IP addresses.

Comment: I will edit to clarify. 10.1.0.5 is how I would like the remote computer to appear on the LAN. 192.168.1.30 is simply a computer on the LAN which may play a part in helping route the remote computer to the 10.1.0.* series.

Comment: The 10.x.x.x subnet is always local. It doesn't pass borders/NAT. There are several million people in the world with the IP address 10.1.0.* How on earth do you think you are going to differentiate yours? IP tunnelling over VPN might be possible, but seems like total overkill to save you having to type a different domain name or address. It's not even like 10.1.0.5 is a good, catchy, memorable name...

Comment: I think I am still not conveying the issue clearly. I want to access a remote computer on my own LAN. 
1) Remote computer connects to my IP address when booted
2) Remote computer is forwarded on my LAN so that its Apache server on /var/www is accessible (ONLY on my LAN) via 10.1.0.5

Comment: Then the solution would be to have a VPN server inside your LAN, that the remote server connects to, so that the VPN server gives the wanted IP-Address to your remote server (which is then a client of your local VPN server)

Comment: If you want a machine (`192.168.1.30`) to be able to access another machine (`10.1.0.5`) within your network that would up to your network Administrator to make it happen. If the subnet `10.1.0.x` is only accessible by VPN that is intentional. However, for the purposes of understand, both of the addresses you have provided ONLY exist within your network.

Comment: @DarkDiamond Yes that is what I want - how can the remote server connect to the VPN inside my LAN? Is there a linux utility for it, or an Apache feature?

Comment: I would recommend to use an OpenVPN server inside your network, and then the correspondig OpenVPN client on your remote server. I do that all the time when I want my laptop to access my home file server, there should be no difference when using a remote server

Comment: Thank you. The OpenVPN server is already set up inside my network. I would have to find out how to set up the OpenVPN client on the remote server.

Comment: Find out what OS your remote server is running, and install the client, then import a pre-configured .ovpn profile and you should be ready to go

Comment: If you need help doing so, reach out here or in some other forum, OpenVPN is widely spread, because it is relatively easy to set up, and very secure